# Unexpected space between two divs with equal width

Tags: css, margin

I have this weird space between my margins, even using margin and padding of 0 for all the elements. Could anyone help me to understand this behavior in Chrome?

Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/rzby6mj7/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child-1">ONE</div>
  <div class="child child-2">TWO</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parent{
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
}

.child{
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child-1{
  background-color: grey;
}

.child-2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Add float:left; on the .child class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that is because of the newline between your two divs. This should do the job

```
<div class="child child-1">ONE</div><div class="child child-2">TWO</div>

or

<div class="child child-1">ONE</div
><div class="child child-2">TWO</div>
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't make sense at all

Comment: @JorgeMonte in fact it makes sense, as html treats ALL transparents spaces  like tabs or \n as spaces and since there are 3 spaces between your divs in your code (one newline and two spaces or a tab), html write that space. Have you tried removing the newline ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, probably someone else did. But yes you helped, I didnt know this behavior of HTML since it doesnt considerate spaces between elements to display. Thank you!

Comment: @JorgeMonte sorry but this is the worst way to fix the issue ... check the duplicate to understand more and get better ways

Comment: Thank you Temani